# Can't locate File/ShareDir/Install.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

I am trying to install PCAP-core-1.8.2/ (https://github.com/ICGC-TCGA-PanCancer/PCAP-core) on CentOS release 6.2 and I keep getting the error when I run:

```
perl Makefile.PL

Can't locate File/ShareDir/Install.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at Makefile.PL line 24.
```

Line 24 is this:

```
use File::ShareDir::Install;
```

I see it can't find File/ShareDir/Install.pm so when I try and find this perl module:

locate Install.pm

I get this:

```
/usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/Install.pm
```

and in my .bashrc file I added this directory - but I am not sure what is going wrong either in the PERL5LIB PATH or elsewhere? Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: You need to install the `File::ShareDir::Install` module. The file returned by locate is not the correct Install.pm. `ExtUtils::Install` is not the same as `File::ShareDir::Install`

Comment: Why not let the CPAN shell handle this sort of stuff for you?